# Batch checking of 1000 records online without batch option. Need automation

Tags: geocoding, batch, web-service, ordnance-survey

Do you know of any method for looping 1000 records over this website?

https://apidocs.os.uk/docs/os-places-match

I would like to check some addresses but OS doesn't provide batch checking.

Comment: curl, postman or python?

Comment: python as I think

Comment: No, those were possible ways to do it - anything that can call a URL will work